# why Backbone sending to ajax request on folder in parent directory?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

*I am new in Backbone, I am working with php as server-side languge.*

when the **urlRoot**  is **../server/books** it is sending two request, one described
*301 Moved Permanently* and the other request under that is *200 OK*.

and when I change the **urlRoot** to **/backbone/server/books/index.php** the ajax request that I see in *firebug* console
become one item and it is **200 OK**.

Why on the address what I use **../** Backbone send two request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, Backbone.JS used jQuery.ajax to send request. By default, the origin of your urls is `/` if you don't indicate any hostname. 
In your case, you set this origin to `../`, for jQuery.Ajax, you leave the current domain to request another.